# How to detect an empty Akka Source

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

In some edge cases I return an empty Source. Is there any way for the caller to check if the returning Source is empty or not before running it?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way for the caller to check if the returning `Source` is empty or not before running it?

No. The only way to determine whether a `Source` is empty is to run it.

Answer (score 1):

> Source
>   A processing stage with exactly one output, emitting data elements whenever downstream processing stages are ready to receive them.

As per definition we can't know the element of source unless a downstream is there to receive.

So As per my understanding we can't check a source is empty or not without running it.
Please feel free to comment your thoughts

I think one way to achieve the requirement is

```
val x: Future[Boolean] = Source.empty.runWith(Sink.seq).transform{
   case Success(lst) => Success(lst.isEmpty)
   case Failure(_) => Success(true)
}
```

Comment: The questions asked specifically to check the source "before running it".

Comment: I have updated the answer . Can you please check it?

Comment: Your answer contradicts itself. You say we can't check whether the source is empty or not but then you say "one way to achieve the requirement is" and provide an example that runs the `Source`.